# Bad to repeat thank you to a co-worker who nominated you?

Tags: professionalism, employer-relations

I recently recieved an award thanking me for my hard-work. First award with my company and also my first year. Below is what I wanted to send to my co-worker who nominated me, but I was unsure if it is wrong to repeat "Thank you/appreciated" as I have done. Below is my message:

```
 Thank you very much! I can’t stress enough how much I appreciate the fact 
 that you took the time out of your busy schedule to submit this and 
 noticed my hard-work. It is extremely appreciated. Thank you.
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: no biggie. don't sweat it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this.  It is a nice thing to do, and it comes across as a thoughtful, professional note.  Also, If you can think of a concrete example of how this co-worker contributed to your success as an employee, it might be kind of nice to throw in a thank you for that too.

Comment: @djohnson10 sounds like an answer to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this. It is a nice thing to do, and it comes across as a thoughtful, professional note.

Also, If you can think of a concrete example of how this co-worker contributed to your success as an employee, it might be kind of nice to throw in a thank you for that too.